importlib.metadata.distributions is not updated after package install
I have a script, which manages client user packages via UI and can install/uninstall them. The problem I met is that after package install the result of calling importlib.metadata.distributions() is not updated to include the new package, when 'site-packages' directory under '%APPDATA%\Python\PythonXY' directory (default for Windows) doesn't exist yet.
Running the following script I expected the number of installed packages to be increased after package install, but it is not. Creating the folder in the beginning of the script does not help.
import importlib.metadata as metadata
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path
from site import USER_SITE

package_name = "some_package_name" # use your own here for test

def outputln(text):
    print(text + '\n')

def get_metadata_distributions_count():
    return (sum(1 for e in metadata.distributions()))  

# below is NOT working
#create user packages folder, if it doesn't exist
Path(USER_SITE).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

outputln("Distributions count= {}".format( get_metadata_distributions_count() ))
cmd_install = [
        path_to_python_exe,
        "-m",
        "pip",
        "install",
        package_name,
        "--user",
    ]
install = subprocess.run(cmd_install)

if install.returncode == 0:
    outputln("Install successful")
    outputln("Distributions count after 1 package install = {}".format(get_metadata_distributions_count() ))

Is this a Python bug or did I miss something? If bug is there a workaround?
Thank you in adavance for your help!

I answer my own question. What actually worked was adding next code in the place of not working one.
# create Python user packages path and add it to sys.path
user_packages_path = Path(site.USER_SITE)
user_packages_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
sys.path.append(user_packages_path)

